# Python interactive shell running copy.py on current directory?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script named `copy.py` on my current directory with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Ahoy, matey!")
```

If I run Python interactive shell and do some action which raise an exception (e.g. referring to non-existent variable), to my surprise, the sentence "Ahoy, matey!" got printed.

When I rename the `copy.py` script to anything else, e.g. `script.py`, it no longer behaves like that. My question is, why the interactive shell have to call `copy.py` on error? Is this behavior expected and/or documented somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python imports a module, the [module search path order](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) is:

- the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- the installation-dependent default.

Now, when raising an exception, Python runs specific code. Any code that tries to import the `copy` Python module will instead import your module and print the string in it. This is why you shouldn't use names that are also names of standard Python modules.

Comment: Makes lot of sense. Thanks a lot, Quentin!

Comment: Terima kasih kembali :)

Comment: Wow you know some Bahasa. I'm surprised :)